# Running `INavigation.PushModalAsync` synchronously in `Xamarin.Forms`

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, synchronization

How to run [`INavigation.PushModalAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.pushmodalasync?view=xamarin-forms) synchronously?

By synchronously, I mean I want to block UI interactions when opening a modal page (e.g. disallowing opening two pages when tapping fast twice).

Comment: if your only concern is fast tap, then I think is better to handle it on your event/command

Comment: Thanks, @Cfun. That's the way I'm handling it right now.

Comment: what is wrong with that way?

Comment: IMO, it would be cleaner if there was a `PushModal` method.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for your reference:

1. There is an **IsEnabled** property in Button, you can first set IsEnabled to false when entering the method. This will make the Button unclickable. This prevents multiple clicks.
2. You can **lock inside your method**. In this way, your logic code will only be executed once. Prevent the code from being executed multiple times due to multiple clicks.

   For information on how to use **Lock**, please refer to: [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock).

Answer (score 0):

As Wen xu Li mentioned in his answer, disabling the UI when an operation is running is the best practice. Here's what that might look like in practice:

MainViewModel.cs

```cs
using MvvmHelpers;
using MvvmHelpers.Commands;

public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject {

    private readonly object longWorkLock = new object();

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy{
        get => _isBusy;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isBusy, value);
    }

    public ICommand DoLongWorkCommand { get; }
    public ICommand DoLongWorkAlternativeWithLock { get; }

    public MainViewModel(){
        DoLongWorkCommand = new AsyncCommand(DoLongWorkAsync);
        DoLongWorkAlternativeWithLock = new AsyncCommand(DoLongWorkAlternativeWithLockAsync);
    }

    private async Task DoLongWorkAsync(){
        if(IsBusy){
            return;
        }
        IsBusy = true;

        //simulate long running work
        await Task.Delay(1234);

        IsBusy = false;
    }

    private async Task DoLongWorkAlternativeWithLockAsync(){
        lock(longWorkLock){
            IsBusy = true;

            //simulate long running work
            await Task.Delay(1234);

            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

MyPage.xaml

```xml
<Button
    Text="Do long work"
    Command="{Binding DoLongWorkCommand}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}" />

<Button
    Text="Do long work (alternative with lock)"
    Command="{Binding DoLongWorkAlternativeWithLockCommand}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}" />
```

Note that I'm using the [MvvmHelpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers) library in this example.